# dynamics crm 2013 c# plugin update/change system user timezone in it's usersettings

Tags: c#, .net, plugins, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

**hello, 
i need to create a plugin to update a new user -timezone immediately
after it created, but i don't know how to update the timezone in the connected usersettings - which attributes (like TimeZoneCode) do i must change 
if i always want to change to time zone to the my country- paris? ,
and how to update?
**my steps:**

1. i create a post operation plugin, on systemuser entity - create
2. get the id of the new systemuser   // systemUser.systemuserid;
3. retrieve its connected userSettings according to the systemuser id

ColumnSet attributes = new ColumnSet(new string[] { "timezonecode" }); 
 var userSettingsResult =
 _service.Retrieve(userSettings.LogicalName, newSystemUserId, attributes);

**4. but i dont know which attributtes i need to update in usersettings to change the genereal time zone

for example: from london to my country paris ( i always change to paris)

do i only need to change the TimeZoneCode or i need to change more attributes like TimeZoneBias?
and if so which attributes and  and how?**

**my code**

```
public void updateNewUserTimeZone(MOHServiceContext myContext, Entity entity, ITracingService trc, IOrganizationService service, IPluginExecutionContext executionContext)
    {           
        if (entity != null)
        {
           // post operation - the new system user
            var systemUser = entity.ToEntity<systemuser>();
            var newSystemUserId=systemUser.systemuserid;  //get the id of the new systemuser

             if (newSystemUserId)
                {
                    //find the userSettingObject that has the same id as the system user now created

                    --var userSettingsResult = (from userSettingObject in myContext.userSettingsSet
                                        --where userSettingObject.systemuserid == newSystemUserId                                            
                                        --select userSettingObject).FirstOrDefault();

                // second way to retrive user setting
                //the fields we wandt to retrive from usersettings
                    ColumnSet attributes = new ColumnSet(new string[] { "timezonecode" }); 

                // Retrieve the usersettings and its timezonecode attribute.
                var userSettingsResult = _service.Retrieve(userSettings.LogicalName, newSystemUserId, attributes);                   




                    //if we find serSettingObject that has the same id as the system user now created
                    if (userSettingsResult != null)
                    {
                    //how to update the time zone in userSettingsResult we found to paris?

                    }
                }


            }
```

***thanks a lot :)
li***

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get the [TimeZoneIndex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms912391(v=winembedded.11).aspx) value and update the user settings  [TimeZoneCode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.messages.convertdateandtimebehaviorrequest.timezonecode.aspx) with the corresponding value.

```
var userSettings = new UserSettings()
{
    Id = userSettingsId,
    TimeZoneCode = 105 //(GMT+01:00) Brussels, Copenhagen, Madrid, Paris
}; 
organizationService.Update(userSettings);
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. You can ignore the other time zone attributes on usersetting - they are system calculated. Only the `TimeZoneCode` should be set.

Comment: hello , thanks a lot !! :-)                                                                                         , so when updating to 105 , which of these countries :Brussels, Copenhagen, Madrid, Paris, will the user/admin see , in the settings                    ->time zone, of that specfic updated user?                                                               i wish to see 'paris' written, how can i make it possible? thanks again!

Comment: @liori they will, in the settings time zone dropdown see `(GMT+01:00) Brussels, Copenhagen, Madrid, Paris`

Comment: Hello,it updates well, only when i run the plugin asynchronous, but when i run it synchronous ,as i needed , i get an error saying-                    the record: usersettings with this id doesn't exist.                                     i need to do it synchronous, how can i change my code so it will happen?                                                                                                              and also can you please tell me when is usersettings record created in crm (async/plugin with higher Execution Order ) ? thanks a lot!!!  li

Comment: @liori, do you get a result back when you query for all usersettings with the User Id the plugin is registered on? this query --> `var userSettingsResult = (from userSettingObject in myContext.userSettingsSet
where userSettingObject.systemuserid == newSystemUserId                                            
select userSettingObject).FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: hye, didn't need it, only the part you wrote here :)

Comment: @liori my answer was a generic pointer, you still need the ID of the user setting entity to update the TimeZoneCode, I have updated my answer. Use the ID from your `userSettingsResult` query and update the entity.

Comment: hye,    my query returned null, but if i run more general query to retrieve all userSettings in the system ,it indeed returned all the userSettings in the system.   so i wander why it doesn't retrieve the userSettings connected to my systemuser and what i need to change?                                                                                        and also when the user setting been created or updated in the process of creating my new user (the plugin is post) . thanks for replaying

Comment: @liori you will have to try it out to see when the user settings entity is created? If it is created synchronously or asynchronously. I would think it is created synchronously, but again if it is not, you might have to re-think your strategy. Also, what drives it to be synchronous? Asynchronous plugins don't take very long the record should be updated within a few seconds, nothing that the user would notice, as they don't really login to the system as soon as you create a user anyway.

Comment: Hello,                                                                                                                well... it worked perffectly well as you worte the code above.  as asynchronously plugin.